# Clearinterval method is unable to clear Rotation javascript animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JS and i am trying to move object from left to right while spinning clockwise, here i applied setinterval for movement animation from left to right and also for rotation. I am able to clearinterval Movement from left to right but unable to clearinterval my Rotation i don't know why please if you can take a look

```js
window.topPos = '';

var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
var s = 1;
var rotate = false;

var degrees = 0;


function myInterval() {
  var eLeftPos = e.offsetLeft;
  e.style.left = (eLeftPos + s) + 'px';


  function rot() {
    degrees++;
    e.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
  }

  var rotID = setInterval(rot, 1000)

  var leftPos = (eLeftPos + s) >= 1000

  if ((eLeftPos + s) >= 1000) {
    clearInterval(rotID)
    console.log(rotID)
  }


  if ((eLeftPos + s) >= 1000) {

    clearInterval(internal)
  }


}

var internal = setInterval(myInterval, 100);
```

```css
#aDiv {
  background: black;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

#aDiv1 {
  background: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="aDiv"></div>
<button>Stop</button>
```

Comment: Well as i mentioned in code at this point if ((eLeftPos + s) >= 1000) {
    clearInterval(rotID)
    console.log(rotID)
  }   interval should be cleared and rotation should be stopped as per definition but it is not happening

Comment: Also can you help me out, what exactly i need to do here if you can help it would be great

Comment: Just to clarify the logic here, ..  Are you wanting to move the rect right for 1 second, then start rotating, and then when the left is greater than 1000 stop?

Comment: I rolled back your edit; you are not allowed to change an existing question into a new one, especially after you have received comments and answers relating to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You're unable to clear the interval from the rotation, because you start a new `setInterval` every time the first (movement) interval executes. You'll have a new rotation interval every 1000ms. Why not just move and rotate within the same `setInterval` callback and then theres only 1 to cancel:

```js
window.topPos = '';

var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
var s = 1;
var rotate = false;

var degrees = 0;


function myInterval() {
  var eLeftPos = e.offsetLeft;
  var leftPos = (eLeftPos + s); // new left pos
    
  e.style.left = leftPos + 'px';
  
  degrees++;
  e.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';    

  if (leftPos >= 100) { // made 100 just to show the effect quicker
    clearInterval(internal)
  }
}

var internal = setInterval(myInterval, 100);
```

```css
#aDiv {
  background: black;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

#aDiv1 {
  background: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="aDiv"></div>
<button>Stop</button>
```